# Django UpdateView with ImageField

Tags: django, django-views, python-imaging-library, django-class-based-views

Form validation isn't passing for some reason when i try to update a image on my model.
I've also tried updating it without using `PIL` library, still doesn't work.

```
class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/edit-profile.html'
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['username'])

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.instance = form.save(commit=False)
        user = self.get_object()
        user.full_name = self.instance.full_name
        user.username = self.instance.username
        user.email = self.instance.email
        user.description = self.instance.description
        im = Image.new(self.instance.main_image)
        user.profile_image = im
        user.ig = self.instance.ig
        user.fb = self.instance.fb
        user.pinterest = self.instance.pinterest
        user.twitter = self.instance.twitter
        user.save()
        return render(self.request, self.template_name, self.get_context_data())
```

Model `Image` attribute

```
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=save_profile_image,
                                     default='/static/img/blog/avatars/user-01.jpg')

def save_profile_image(instance, filename):
    if instance:
        return '{}/{}'.format(instance.id, filename)
```

form data from html.

```
                <form action="" class="tm-edit-product-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<div class="custom-file mt-3 mb-3">
                                <input id="fileInput" type="file" name="main_image" style="display: none"
                                       accept="image/*"/>
                                {{ form.profile_image }}
                            </div>

</form>
```

Anyway, the `POST` request comes throgh but the object isn't updated. The problem resides in the `ImageField`. Why the hell isn't it working as it should?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to bind the model to the updateview:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#updateview

then you don't need the form_valid anymore

```
class UpdateProfile(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'dashboard/edit-profile.html'
    model = User
    form_class = UserForm
    success_url = None

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

Comment: yes i have and it doesn't matter if i bind it if i'm overriding `get_object`

Comment: ok so you removed the form_valid override and tried?

also you have `.instance.main_image` in the `form_valid` can you check the value of that? shouldn't it be `instance.profile_image`

Comment: i've found the error, in my `forms.py`  i had custom `js` and `css` attached to it. I've removed them and tried with basic `form.FileInput()` `field` and it workerd.

Comment: would have been my next question to show the form xD

glad you found the mistake